# Vista MySql con parámetros no funciona

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buen dia hoy realize esta consulta, la consulta realiza es comparar el tipo explosivo_id para luego sumar la entrada y restar la salida antes de eso guarda un saldo

```
SELECT  T.kardex_fechaRegistro, T.explosivo_id, T.kardex_tipo, T.kardex_cantidad, T.saldo FROM ( SELECT explosivo_id, kardex_fechaRegistro, kardex_tipo, kardex_cantidad,   CASE 
    WHEN (@EXPLOSIVO = '' OR @EXPLOSIVO = vek.explosivo_id) AND kardex_tipo = 'entrada' THEN @SALDO:= @SALDO + veK.kardex_cantidad
    WHEN (@EXPLOSIVO = '' OR @EXPLOSIVO = vek.explosivo_id) AND kardex_tipo = 'salida' THEN @SALDO:= @SALDO - veK.kardex_cantidad
    WHEN @EXPLOSIVO != explosivo_id AND kardex_tipo = 'entrada' THEN @SALDO := 0 + kardex_cantidad
    WHEN @EXPLOSIVO != explosivo_id AND kardex_tipo = 'salida' THEN @SALDO := 0 - kardex_cantidad   END AS saldo,   @EXPLOSIVO:= explosivo_id FROM tvalexplosivos_kardex AS vek ORDER BY veK.explosivo_id, veK.kardex_fechaRegistro ) T;
```

Mi resultado fue el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi problema cuando lo paso en una vista no me funciona, el codigo esta asi:

```
SELECT  T.kardex_fechaRegistro, T.explosivo_id, T.kardex_tipo, T.kardex_cantidad, T.saldo
FROM (
SELECT explosivo_id, kardex_fechaRegistro, kardex_tipo, kardex_cantidad,
  CASE 
    WHEN (explosivo() = '' OR explosivo() = vek.explosivo_id) AND kardex_tipo = 'entrada' THEN saldo()= saldo()+veK.kardex_cantidad
    WHEN (explosivo() = '' OR explosivo() = vek.explosivo_id) AND kardex_tipo = 'salida' THEN saldo()= saldo()-veK.kardex_cantidad
    WHEN explosivo() != explosivo_id AND kardex_tipo = 'entrada' THEN saldo()= 0+kardex_cantidad
    WHEN explosivo() != explosivo_id AND kardex_tipo = 'salida' THEN saldo()= 0-kardex_cantidad
  END AS saldo,
  explosivo()= explosivo_id
FROM tvalexplosivos_kardex AS vek
ORDER BY veK.explosivo_id, veK.kardex_fechaRegistro
) T
```

cree mis functiones, me guie de esta pagina https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/38743/puedo-crear-una-vista-con-parametros-en-mysql

pero me resulta asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor ayudenme, gracias

Comment: No puedes usar variables de sistema o usuario en vistas. Puedes usar un procedimiento aunque tendrías algunas limitantes.

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo?

Comment: El ejemplo de la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html#sa51760584) te sirve, pero sin la variable de salida. ¿Qué versión de MySQL usas?.